# Matrix product of entire functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, matrix-analysis

Suppose I have two $d \times d$ entire matrix functions $F, G$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$ with the the property that $\|FG^*\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{C})} < \infty$. Can anything be said about $F$ and $G$, or even the product $FG$?

Trivially one has $\|\det FG\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{C})} < \infty$ and so by Liouville's theorem $\det FG$ is constant, but I don't really see what is useful about this, other than  either both $F$ and $G$ are invertible everywhere,  or that for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ either $F(z)$ or $G(z)$ (or both) are singular.

Any thoughts or places to look would be very helpful!

Note: for further context, this question immediately pops up when looking at bounded Toeplitz products $T_F T_{G^*}$ on the Segal Bargman/Fock space with entire symbols $F$ and $G$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but it's not possible to conclude that $F$, $G$, or $FG$ is bounded (constant). There is the trivial counterexample $$F=\begin{pmatrix} f & 0 \\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}, \quad G=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & g \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: Christian, yes thanks for mentioning trivial counterexamples like this.